# Observable find method not working

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a list of menuItems and possible submenuItems that are loaded from a json via a service. On route change, a lookup of the parent menu is done to open the correct menuItem. I do this using an Observable list of menuItems.

The MenuItem class is as follows:

```
export class MenuItem {
  code: string;
  name: string;
  routerLink: boolean;
  submenu: boolean;
  url: string;
  submenuItems: SubMenuItem[];
}
```

The submenuItem is as follows:

```
export class SubMenuItem {
  name: string;
  url: string;
  routerLink: boolean;
}
```

To find the correct menuItem is use the following method:

```
private findParentMenuToExpand(url:String): Observable<MenuItem> {
console.log("inside findParentMenuToExpand");

return this.menuItems$
  .find((menuItem: MenuItem) => {
    if (menuItem.submenu === true) {
      for (let subMenuItem of menuItem.submenuItems) {
        if (subMenuItem.url === url) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

that method is called as follows:

```
if(this.selectedSubMenuUrl != null) {
  var parentMenuItem: Observable<MenuItem> = this.findParentMenuToExpand(this.selectedSubMenuUrl);
  parentMenuItem.subscribe((menuItem: MenuItem) => console.log(menuItem));
}
```

the menuItem in the subscribe method however is always undefined.

Any clues as to what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `find` - does it log the MenuItems correctly then?

Comment: yes, the menuItems are correctly inserted

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because your code doesn't reach the return statement.
I'd suggest debugging the values emitted by `menuItems$` to see if `find` operator should emit something.

```
return this.menuItems$
  .do((v) => {
     console.log(v.submenu, v.submenuItems);
   })
  .find((menuItem: MenuItem) => {
    if (menuItem.submenu === true) {
      for (let subMenuItem of menuItem.submenuItems) {
        if (subMenuItem.url === url) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```